# How to Play Video (MP4 format) in IE , Firefox, Chrome,

Tags: html

How to Play Video (MP4 format) in IE , Firefox, Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a windows media player object tag

```
<object width="100%" height="100%"
type="video/x-ms-asf" url="Video/Home.mp4" data="Video/Home.mp4"
classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
<param name="url" value="Video/Home.mp4">
<param name="filename" value="Video/Home.mp4">
<param name="autostart" value="1">
<param name="uiMode" value="full">
<param name="autosize" value="1">
<param name="playcount" value="1"> 
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="Video/Home.mp4" width="100%" height="100%"       autostart="true" showcontrols="true"  pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed>
</object>
```

Also if the browser doesn't have the plugin to play it, it will propmt you to download one specific to your browser. But there is no other way to create a cross browser player without plug-ins(as far as my knowledge goes)

Comment: its working..!!! okay Thanks you for all @Shinobi_Lunga and one more thing i want to ask you how to place a image on the video. when click on it video should play on this embed tag

Answer (score 0):

use `<video>` tag to embed the video

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp

Comment: thank you so much for response but here it is HTML5 tag which is not working in the IE browser, i have check it, is there any other solution to play mp4 video in all borwser's

Comment: you will have to use `<object>` tag to embed video in old browsers. You would need Flash player for this. `<object id=0 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data=player_flv_maxi.swf width=512 height=380>
<param name="movie" value=player_flv_maxi.swf />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="flv=movie1.flv&width=512&height=380" />
</object>`